# Handle ECONNRESET in nodejs https.request

Tags: node.js, error-handling

So sometimes there is network or server issues and https.request fails with ECONNRESET. I think the proper thing to do would be to retry with exponential backoff delays, starting with none, and building up to several hours. But if it's easier I could just use a 5 minute delay. I've read an article on asynchronous error handling, but I haven't been able to find any examples for something simple like this. Could I get a working example please?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there is a library I should be using like backoff or socket.io?

Comment: I'd met the error often, because my project's port has been used, you can check which port your project run and kill it, or change an other port to run

Answer (score 1):

Just attach an `error` event handler on the request object:

```
var req = https.request(...);
req.on('error', function(err) {
  // handler `err` here ...
});
```

With retries:

```
// waits 1 second on first error, then 2, then 4, then 8, etc.
function makeRequest(url, lastTimeout) {
  lastTimeout || (lastTimeout = 500);
  var req = https.request(url, ...);
  req.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    lastTimeout *= 2;
    setTimeout(makeRequest, lastTimeout, url, lastTimeout);
  });
}

// call function
makeRequest('https://google.com');
```

You will probably want to put some kind of upper bound on the retries though, so it doesn't retry indefinitely. You could also add to `lastTimeout` a random number of milliseconds to make it less exactly exponential every time.

Comment: So then put your call to `https.request()` inside a function that you call from your `error` event handler.